# C# pass parameter in querystring to WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, query-string, querystringparameter

I currently have a WPF application that needs to accept a parameter from a URL like it would in ASP.NET. I have looked through previous post on SO but nothing it seems to be as clear as mud. I have already changed the section in "Publish" to for the acceptance of parameters as well. The follow is the code I am utilizing:

```
using System;
using System.Deployment;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using ViewImageForm;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Deployment.Application;

namespace WPFHost
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        private readonly Form1 mainForm = new Form1();

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Create a Windows Forms Host to host a form
        WindowsFormsHost windowsFormsHost = new WindowsFormsHost();

        stackPanel.Width = mainForm.Width;
        stackPanel.Height = mainForm.Height;
        windowsFormsHost.Width = mainForm.Width;
        windowsFormsHost.Height = mainForm.Height;

        mainForm.TopLevel = false;

        windowsFormsHost.Child = mainForm;

        stackPanel.Children.Add(windowsFormsHost);
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        {
        string url =
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[
        0];
        string queryString = (new Uri(url)).Query;
        this.textBox1.Text = queryString;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I take it that URL has some data you want?

Comment: Or is the ActivationData just not what you expect?, with your code, the text box will just have its text set to the query string of the ActivationData[0] URL

Comment: @LordTakkera the URL is http:\\website.us?DKT_ID=param. I am really struggling to get this one and only param from the URL to the textbox in my WPF application.

Comment: @LordTakkera I've never used WPF so this is all new to me. Can you explain a little more as this is not like ASP.NET where I can just call upon the query string. :-(

Comment: No problem, I'm pretty sure I can help you, I just need to know if you want the string "DKT_ID=param", and can or can't see the the url you provided in your debugger; or, if you want data from that URL, as in a HTTP GET to go out and use the response somehow.

Comment: @LordTakkera from the URL because it is all internal.

Comment: Still not sure exactly what you need, my attempt at both possiblities below.

Comment: @LordTakkera basically, I need the one value of the parameter, DKT_ID, to be populated to a textbox and then the winform (which is a class library, will open a winform exe.

Comment: Ok, does the update do what you want?

Comment: @LordTakkera here is my current URL: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ViewImages2\WPFHost.xbap. It isn't allowing me to add the ?DKT_ID=param to the end of it.

Comment: It won't, and shouldn't. You can't have query strings in a windows path. If this is a web app, which I am assuming given you are using the XBAP format, does launching it from the browser work with the query string? This blog post seems like a good place to start: http://learnwpf.com/post/2007/02/25/How-can-I-pass-Querystring-parameters-to-my-WPF-XBAP-Application.aspx

Comment: @LordTakkera thank you. I'll use the site you sent. With my current code above, how would I implement what you sent below? I appreciate the help.

Comment: If all you want is the value of "param" in your example, use the update. Both versions will work with either the full URL. If you get the Query string from the Uri class, and need the "full" version, just eliminate the "Split('?')[1]" since that has been done for you already. Let me know if that doesn't make sense, or you would like my answer modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still not sure about what you are asking, so I'll try to answer both.

If the "url" field is the string "http:\website.us?DKT_ID=param", you can get the string "DKT_ID=param" by using

```
url.Split('?')[1]
```

Creating a Uri object does not do anything other than parse your string into a special object, if you want to peform an HTTP Get and use data from that URL, use something like the example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (
          "http:\\website.us?DKT_ID=param");
        // If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        // Display the content.
        textBox1.Text = responseFromServer;
        // Clean up the streams and the response.
        reader.Close ();
        response.Close ();
```

**Update**
If you want just the "param" string, and there won't be ANY other parameters in the query string, just use

```
url.Split('=')[1]
```

If there are multiple parameters, then you need to do something like

```
Dictionary<String,String> params;
string[] queryParams = url.Split('?')[1].Split('&');
foreach (string s in queryParams)
{
   string[] queryParameter = s.Split('=');
   params.Add(queryParameter[0], queryParameter[1]);
}

textBox1.Text = queryParams["DKT_ID"];
```